# Log PHP errors per script

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

Is there an easy way to log PHP errors to a log for a specific script.  So say I have 5 different scripts each one would have its own error log?

Comment: The answer for that is **yes**, there is a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the name of the log file, by using `ini_set()` ([PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)) in conjunction with `error_log` ([PHP docu](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)):

```
ini_set( 'error_log', 'yourFileName' );
```

If you specify a different file in each script, you will have seperate log files for them all.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could have separate **set_error_handler** for each script.

Comment: You don't even need a separate error handler for each. If you do it correctly, you can have a single one for all 5.

Answer (score 1):

See [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php). Other than that, you can use `ini_set` (see [Sirko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314386/1494505))

Answer (score 0):

you could simply create that on your own.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php

Just build a small function and call it in every of your 5 scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this purely under Apache, you can hack together something like:

```
<Location /path/to/script1.php>
   php_value error_log script1.log
</Location>

<Location /path/to/script2.php>
    php_value error_log script2.log
</Location>

etc...
```

in your .htaccess/httpd.conf.